Relationship between two entities through partial primary keys
In my Spring Boot project I have the following JPA entities:
@Entity
@Table(name = "T1", schema = "t1_schema")
@Data
public class T1Entity {

    @EmbeddedId
    private T1Id id;

    @Column(name = "T1_COD")
    private String code;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "T2_L1", referencedColumnName = "T1_K3")
    private Set<T2Entity> t2Entities;

    @Data
    @Embeddable
    public static class T1Id implements Serializable {

        @Convert(converter = TrimConverter.class)
        @Column(name = "T1_K1")
        private String k1;

        @Convert(converter = TrimConverter.class)
        @Column(name = "T1_K2")
        private String k2;

        @Convert(converter = TrimConverter.class)
        @Column(name = "T1_K3")
        private String k3;
    }

}

and
@Entity
@Table(name = "T2", schema = "t2_schema")
@Data
public class T2Entity {

    @EmbeddedId
    private T2Id id;

    @Data
    @Embeddable
    public static class T2Id implements Serializable {

        @Column(name = "T2_L1")
        @Convert(converter = TrimConverter.class)
        private String l1;

        @Column(name = "T2_L2")
        @Convert(converter = TrimConverter.class)
        private String l2;

        @Column(name = "T2_L3")
        @Convert(converter = TrimConverter.class)
        private String l3;
    }

}

The relationship between T1 and T2 is not well seen, I have the following error:
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Referenced column 't1_k3' mapped by target property 'id' occurs out of order in the list of '@JoinColumn's

The goal is to have a set of T2 entities whose l1 field is equal to the k3 field of the T1 entity
Can anyone explain why, and how to resolve it? I am forced to use entity and not native sql and/or HQL or JPQL.

your mapping doesn't make sense to me. T1_K3 doesn't uniquely identify a T1Entity, so the T2Entity can reference many T1Entity instances (it isn't a ManyToOne). And you have it setup so that JPA will set the T2_L1 column value based on 'any' parent T1Entity's T1_K3 value - but it is also set through the T2Entity.id.l1 property. That is too many mappings trying to set the same field. So the first question - are you stuck with this DB schema or can you change it? Second, what is the actual identifier you can use for T1Entity instances?
